# Iterating over a list of objects to collect information, while calculating averages

Tags: javascript

**What I've Done:** I have an array of objects that represent baseball players. I've created a new array, `years` to collect needed information that I'm collecting while iterating through the array. I need to create an object for each year that each player played (referencing `firstSeason` and `lastSeason`), and then I have an array within the same object to collect each player's batting average from each year they played. If the year already exists in the array, it's appended to that object in the array--if it's not, a new object is created for that year and added to the array.

**What I'm having trouble with:** Along with an object for each year played, and the array with each player's batting average for that year, I also want to have another property in the `years` array that will show the overall average for each year--so essentially every `avg` array item in `years` added together and divided by the length of the `avg` array.

I know how to do this by re-looping over the `years` array, but I'm trying to accomplish this during the initial iteration... within the `for (var season in baseballSeasons) { }`. So, if needed, perhaps a running average while the loop is running that continues compiling the averages as they come in, if that makes sense.

Code:

```js
    var baseballSeasons = [
        {
            PlayerName: "Dave",
            FirstSeason: 2013,
            LastSeason: 2016,
            BattingAverageRecord: [340, 210, 220, 300]
        },
        {
            PlayerName: "Dennis",
            FirstSeason: 2013,
            LastSeason: 2016,
            BattingAverageRecord: [230, 221, 312, 240]
        },
        {
            PlayerName: "Mary",
            FirstSeason: 2010,
            LastSeason: 2013,
            BattingAverageRecord: [330, 123, 151, 307]
        }
    
    ];
    
    var years = [];
    
    for (var season in baseballSeasons) {
    
        var firstYear = baseballSeasons[season].FirstSeason;
        var numberOfYears = baseballSeasons[season].BattingAverageRecord.length;
    
        for (var x = 0; x < numberOfYears; x++) {
    
            const yearExists = years.some(el => el.year === firstYear);
            var avgForYear = baseballSeasons[season].BattingAverageRecord[x];
    
            if (!yearExists) {
                years.push({ year: firstYear, avg: [avgForYear] })
            } else {
                let obj = years.find(o => o.year === firstYear);
                obj.avg.push(avgForYear);
            }
    
            firstYear++;
        }
    
    }
    
    console.log(years);
```

Example of the output:

```
0:
   year: 2013
   avg: (3) [340, 230, 307]
```

Desired output:

```
0:
   year: 2013
   avg: (3) [340, 230, 307]
   yearAverage: 292
```

`yearAverage` is just the sum of the avg array divided by the array length. I'm unsure how to collect this in my existing loop.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the expected output exactly?

Comment: I just edited the original post with desired output.

Comment: Why do you need to do it all in one loop? You won't be able to compute the average without all of the numbers, so the only way to do it in one loop is to continually re-compute the average from a running total whenever a new number arrives. Seems a lot clunkier than just computing the averages one time when you have all of the necessary information. Are you experiencing a performance bottleneck of some sort? Also, the result array seems sort of difficult to use. An object with year keys mapped to their data seems easier--O(1) indexing.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback. I really just wanted to see if there's an easy way to do this within one iteration though I totally get what you're saying about that being a performance hit, especially with a lot of data. 

I'm really curious about the object w/ mapped keys--so you'd recommend a single object instead of an array, using keys for years?

Comment: Yes, unless there's a compelling reason to have it in an array. If I was using this data, I'd want to know instantly what the average is for 2012. I can access it intuitively and efficiently with `yearAverages[2012]` instead of `yearAverages.find(e => e.year === 2012)`.

Comment: I second that, you can access it more easily using the year as a key instead of using an array and having to iterate the array's element one by one to find the year value that you need inside said element.

Comment: The data, `baseballSeasons` that I'm working with will actually be coming from an API that returns data in the format of an array of objects, so I guess keeping it in that same format was my first thought. This is part of an Angular project where I'll be displaying the data in a table--it just seemed like an array would do better in that case... but I'm sure I could do the same with a master object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since computing the average requires all of the numbers, the only way to do it in the loop would be to keep running totals per year somewhere and recompute the average whenever a new number is added to a year. Instead of managing this extra state, it's not much more or less complicated or efficient to run another loop at the end.

```js
const baseballSeasons = [{ PlayerName: "Dave", FirstSeason: 2013, LastSeason: 2016, BattingAverageRecord: [340, 210, 220, 300] }, { PlayerName: "Dennis", FirstSeason: 2013, LastSeason: 2016, BattingAverageRecord: [230, 221, 312, 240] }, { PlayerName: "Mary", FirstSeason: 2010, LastSeason: 2013, BattingAverageRecord: [330, 123, 151, 307] } ];

const years = baseballSeasons.reduce((a, e) =>
  e.BattingAverageRecord.forEach((avg, i) => {
    a[e.FirstSeason+i] = (a[e.FirstSeason+i] || []).concat(avg);
  }) || a
, {});

const result = Object.entries(years).map(([year, avg]) =>
  ({year, avg, yearAverage: avg.reduce((a, e) => a + e) / avg.length | 0})
);

console.log(result);
```

Other thoughts:

- The output array format is unusual. I'd think an object with year keys pointing to their data is easier to use. The lookup is O(1) vs O(n) and more idiomatic: `years[2012].avg` rather than `years.find(e => e.year === 2012).avg`.
- Similarly, while building the `years` array, `.some` and `.find` search the entire structure. Using an object to group the years during this intermediate step would have a much more significant performance impact than avoiding a second loop for computing averages. This approach builds the more useful result structure on the spot.
- Object keys should be camelCased, not TitleCased (but you mentioned the data is from an API, so that's probably a non-issue).

Comment: Thanks so much. This is incredibly helpful! I'm going to use an object instead of an array for this and see how it goes.

Comment: No problem. If you're just iterating or dumping all the data to HTML, a sorted array makes the most sense, but if you're querying the object repeatedly, it doesn't make much sense (and iterating through an object is easy using `Object.entries` or `in`, so it's a reasonable choice for iteration too).

Comment: Thanks again. I know the basics of `array.reduce()` but I'm working through your solution to try and get a complete understanding of how it works. Question: in the return portion of the reduce, after the forEach you have `|| a` -- what does this do exactly?

Comment: This is just overterseness or overfamiliarity with the idiom on my part. You can change it to use braces and `return a;` if you prefer. `forEach` returns undefined, so `undefined || a` evaluates to `a` always and passes the accumulator to the next iteration. All this `reduce` does is build an object grouping each year mapped to its respective average array.